# MYSQL Error # 1452

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

One is Customer table 
With ---

```
CustomerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL
Address CHAR (100) Not NULL
CITY CHAR (30) Not NULL
```

Then I have another Table  called Orders
with ----

```
OrdersID  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
CustomerID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
Amount FLOAT(6,2)
Date DATE NOT NULL
```

---

Now I am trying to add a foreign Key for CustomerID and REFERENCE Customers(CustomerID)

I am using this command but am getting a #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
ALTER TABLE LA_Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES LA_Customers(CustomerID)
```

I have already made sure InnoDB matches.

Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: The CustomerID  - has '0'  populated  - would that matter

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if `LA_Orders` already has data and has invalid `CustomerID` columns.

You can find them  using:

```
select lo.*
from LA_Orders lo
where lo.CustomerID not in (select lc.CustomerID from LA_Customers lc);
```

(Actually, this assumes that `LA_Customers(CustomerID)` is not `NULL`.  It should be a primary key, so that should be true.)